# C# Defining the Length of a Generic created using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics

I have code like this:

```
Type typPrecise = MostPrecise(typeof(int), typeof(double));//Evaluates to double

var varGeneric = typeof(Number<>);
var varSpecific = varGeneric.MakeGenericType(typPrecise);
dynamic nmNumber = Activator.CreateInstance(varSpecific);
```

The nmNumber is of dynamic type and essentially produces a Generic Number.  How do I then specify the number of items in Number.

I basically  want to accomplish this but by using the dynamic code above:

```
Number<typPrecise> whatever = new Number<typPrecise>(10);
```

An answer using 4.0 concepts is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the overload of Activator.CreateInstance that accepts constructor arguments:

```
dynamic nmNumber = Activator.CreateInstance(varSpecific, new object[] { 10 });
```

Incidentally note that the `List<T>(int)` constructor sets the initial *capacity* of the List, not the initial number of items (Count).  The initial Count is always 0.

Comment: How did I *not* know about an overload of CreateInstance that includes arguments? Doh!

Comment: So the 10 in the object[] just specifies the number of items.  It doesn't add an object[] with a single item of 10?